# How to setup IIS or WCF service for access to local resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that runs under IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.  Calling the service is working just fine from other client machines.  However, the issue is that inside of the WCF service, it needs to run code that requires access to the registry and files on the local machine (including in Windows and Program Files and Program Files (x86).  The AppPool was originally set to NETWORKSERVICE but was failing when trying to access the local resources.  I changed it to my login account which has all the rights needed.  However, the WCF service is still failing.  Is the AppPool user (and rights) being overridden in the WCF service?  I did not do anything unique for the WCF service.  I used the default setup that Visual Studio 2013 uses to create it for .NET 4.5.

Here is my web.config file if that helps:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647"
        executionTimeout="300" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
          sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Comment: No exception from within my service but the API calls I am making to a third party software are not finding what they need access to.

Comment: From a registry perspective, make sure you are looking in the correct hive -- remember, there is a 32bit and 64bit hive for HKLM\Software.  You will access the appropriate one based on the bitness of your process.  If the 3rd party is a 32bit component, it will be under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node if access from an Assembly compiled as Any CPU or x64.